# React: form is clean when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new using React. I have a component called UpserProfile that fetch data from Firebase and put this data in a form. The goal is that the user be able to edit his data/profile.

The problem is: the data is loaded when I load the page. However, if I refresh the page, the form fields become empty/clean. What I'm doing wrong? Someone can help me to increase the code, please?

```
    class UserProfile extends React.Component{
    
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                authUser: null,
                userProfile: new UserProfileModel() // A model with all available properties seted with default values
            }
        }
    
    /**
     * Use auth listner to see if it had an user authenticated
     */
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
            this.props.firebase.getUserData(authUser.uid).then((response)=>{     
                this.setState({ userProfile: {
                    id: response.id,
                    displayName: response.displayName || "", 
                    name: response.name || "", 
                    email: response.email || "",
                }});
            });
        });
    }
    
    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        let value = event.target.value;
        // If it's the termsAndPrivacy checkbox 
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: value});
    }
    
    
    onSubmit = (event) => {
        // Prevent to submit the form
        event.preventDefault();
    
        this.props.firebase.user(this.userProfile.id).set(this.userProfile)
          .then(authUser => {
              console.log("Changed user:", authUser);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error: ", error);
            this.setState({ error });
        });
    }
    
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <BreadCrumb pageTitle="Edit Profile"/>
                <section className="container main-content">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div className="page-content">
                                <div className="boxedtitle page-title"><h2>Edit Profile</h2></div>
                                <div className="form-style form-style-4">
                                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                                        <div className="form-inputs clearfix">
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Display Name*</label>
                                                <input name="displayName" type="text" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.userProfile.displayName}/>
                                            </p>    
                                            <p>
                                                <label>Full name</label>
                                                <input name="name" type="text" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.userProfile.name}/>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <label className="required">E-Mail<span>*</span></label>
                                                <input name="email" type="email" onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.userProfile.email}/>
                                            </p>...
```

Can someone help me, please?

UPDATE:
This is my Firebase Class:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import { UserProfileModel } from '../Models/UserProfileModel';

 const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AI------------------",
    authDomain: "mysite.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://mysite.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "myprojectid",
    storageBucket: "mysite.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "---------1",
    appId: "1--------------"
  };

  export default class Firebase {
    constructor() {
      app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      this.auth = app.auth();
      this.db = app.database();
    }

async getUserData(uid){
      var userData = new UserProfileModel();
      this.user(uid).on('value', (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
              var keyName = childSnapshot.key;
              var childData = childSnapshot.val();
              userData[keyName] = childData;
          });
      });
      return userData;
    }

    // *** USER APO ***

    user = uid => this.db.ref(`users/${uid}`);
    users = () => this.db.ref('users');
```

Comment: Hi @william this is the expected behaviour of a react component. I will get unmounted and state is cleared when you refresh the app.

Comment: @rashijain, how to prevent it? It is not supposed to refresh the data again too?

Comment: no, we need to save the data continuously if we want to persist the data even after refreshing the page without making a submit call. 
We need to make an API call in the componentDidMount as well to get the data from server and fill in the appropriate fields.(This data API call is already there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to sync with your Firebase database using `Rebase` for example:

Firebase.js:

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({ apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL, });
const base = Rebase.createClass(firebaseApp.database());

export { firebaseApp };

export default base;
```

App.js:

```
import base from '../Firebase';


componentDidMount() {
  ...

  this.ref = base.syncState(newState, {
    context: this,
    state: state
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand where to put this rebase, etc. Now, I'm using a separate Class called Firebase.js where I have Firebase settings (apiKey domain, etc) and where I do the connection with the Firebase. Is there where I must to put this component didMount()?

Comment: Typically the firebase and rebase would be in a separate file (Firebase.js in your case) and `componentDidMount()` would be in your App.js file. I'll update the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure once you refresh the page the firebase calls occur again. This will set the new data to state variable and the data will be prefilled.

Comment: Thx. But, how to make sure of that? It is not supposed to happen when I refresh and componentDidMount again? Is something about the way that I'm calling the firebase API, passing it by props?